# Is a group of order 2017 simple?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, simple-groups

I know I need to use Sylow's theorems, I would normally find how many Sylow p subgroups there are of each prime factor and then work out whether they are unique or not to determine if they're simple. But since 2017 is prime, I don't know how to go about it, any ideas?

Comment: The only odd simple groups are the ones of prime order.

Comment: Any group of prime order is both simple and cyclic.

Answer (score 5):

It is simple, because if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ with $|G|=2017$, then $|H|$ would divide 2017 by Lagrange's theorem. So $|H|=1$ or $|H|=2017$